# Spark list all cached RDD names and unpersist

Tags: java, scala, dataframe, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to Apache Spark, I created several RDD's and DataFrames, cached them, now I want to unpersist some of them by using the command below

```
rddName.unpersist()
```

but I can't remember their names. I used `sc.getPersistentRDDs` but the output does not include the names. I also used the browser to view the cached rdds but again no name information. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Dikei's answer is actually correct but I believe what you are looking for is `sc.getPersistentRDDs` :

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.makeRDD(1 to 100)
# rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at makeRDD at <console>:27

scala> val rdd2 = sc.makeRDD(10 to 1000)
# rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at makeRDD at <console>:27

scala> rdd2.cache.setName("rdd_2")
# res0: rdd2.type = rdd_2 ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at makeRDD at <console>:27

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
# res1: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map(1 -> rdd_2 ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at makeRDD at <console>:27)

scala> rdd1.cache.setName("foo")
# res2: rdd1.type = foo ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at makeRDD at <console>:27

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
# res3: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map(1 -> rdd_2 ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at makeRDD at <console>:27, 0 -> foo ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at makeRDD at <console>:27)
```

Now let's add another `RDD` and name it as well :

```
scala> rdd3.setName("bar")
# res4: rdd3.type = bar ParallelCollectionRDD[2] at makeRDD at <console>:27

scala> sc.getPersistentRDDs
# res5: scala.collection.Map[Int,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_]] = Map(1 -> rdd_2 ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at makeRDD at <console>:27, 0 -> foo ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at makeRDD at <console>:27)
```

We noticed that actually it isn't persisted.

Answer (score 12):

PySparkers: getPersistentRDDs [isn't yet implemented in Python](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2141), so unpersist your RDDs by dipping into Java:

```
for (id, rdd) in spark.sparkContext._jsc.getPersistentRDDs().items():
    rdd.unpersist()
```

Answer (score 1):

Scala generic way of doing this ... loop through spark context get all persistent RDDs and `unpersist`.

I will use this at the end of a driver.

```
for ( (id,rdd) <- sparkSession.sparkContext.getPersistentRDDs ) {
      log.info("Unexpected cached RDD " + id)
      rdd.unpersist()
    }
```

Java Generic way of doing this ... where jsc is JavaSparkContext

```
 if (jsc != null) {
                Map<Integer, JavaRDD<?>> persistentRDDS = jsc.getPersistentRDDs();
                // using for-each loop for iteration over Map.entrySet()
                for (Map.Entry<Integer, JavaRDD<?>> entry : persistentRDDS.entrySet()) {
                    LOG.info("Key = " + entry.getKey() +
                            ", un persisting cached RDD = " + entry.getValue().unpersist());
                }

            }
```

Another short form of `unpersist` in java with out knowing rdd names are :

```
Map<Integer, JavaRDD<?>> persistentRDDS = jsc.getPersistentRDDs();
persistentRDDS.values().forEach(JavaRDD::unpersist);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no special meaning to the `rrdName` variable. It is just a reference to an RDD. For example, in the following code

```
val rrdName: RDD[Something]
val name2 = rrdName
```

`name2` and `rrdName` are two references that point to the same RDD. Calling `name2.unpersist` is the same as calling `rrdName.unpersist`.

If you want to `unpersist` an RDD, you have to manually keep a reference to it.