# How to unpersist when we use cant refer to the dataframe

Tags: java, apache-spark, caching

I am using java and my spark code/functionality is written across multiple methods. Usually I end up persisting dataframe in a particular method and not be able to unpersist within the same method, as I would like to wait till the actions on dependent dataframes are performed. So how would I unpersist this cached data at a later point in some other method? I would not be able to access the variable which I used to call for persist originally. Below code can explain.

```
Dataset<Row> Method1 { 
   dfm1 = ... ;
   dfm1.persist();
   dfm12 = dfm1.filter();
   dfm13 = dfm1.filter();
   dfm13.save (to dataset);
   return dfm12;
}

Method2 (DF Dataset<Row>) {
   dfm21 = DF.join(lookup table....);
   dfm21.save(to a dataset);
}

Main(){
   ....
   Dataset<Row> DF = Method1();
   ...
   ...
   Method2(DF);

}
```

Comment: Define the dataframe globally in class and then do operations without passing or returning the dataframe or else if possible persist the dataframe in between two separate function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508577/spark-list-all-cached-rdd-names-and-unpersist

Comment: In most cases, I just use `spark.catalog.clearCache()` to wipe all cached RDDs after the tables are persisted